# Unity3D - What file format should I store my replays

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I a making a state saving replay system in Unity3D and I want the replay to be written to a file. What file format is best to use when saving an replay? Xml maybe? For now I'm storing the transform data and I've implemented the option to add additional frame data.

Comment: I would say that it depends on what information you are storing. Are you just serializing objects?? Or do you wish to have some data consistency? Depending on the answer, the suggestion will vary from a simple binary file, JSON or a full fledged RDBMS

Comment: I'm storing the position, rotation and scale every frame if it is changed. And I want the user to be able to add custom info such as the sprite offset.

Comment: I think you will be better off marshalling your "record" into a binary file that you store somewhere. What I propose: Create a class called `Frame`, create another class called `Record` which has a `List<Frame> frames`. Since you can't marshall a list, you will have to marshal each frame and concatenate it's binary content somehow (I suggest appending to the binary file instead of concatenating the binary content in memory). Save the result in a file for each record `record1.yourgame`. Now, you can place anything as a attribute of the `Frame` class that is marshallable.

Comment: @NicolasCaous could you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It highly depends on what you are trying to do. There are tradeoffs for every solution in this case.

Based on the extra information you have given in the comments, the best solution I can think of in this case is [marshalling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)) your individual "recording sessions" onto a file. However, there is a little overhead to be done in order to achieve this.

1. Create a class called `Frame`, create another class called `Record` which has a `List<Frame> frames`. That way, you can place any information that you would like to be captured in each frame as attributes in the `Frame` class.
2. Since you can't marshal a generic type, you will have to marshall each frame individually. I suggest implementing a method in the `Record` class called `MarshalRecording()` that handles that for you.
3. However, in doing that, you will find it difficult to unmarshal your records because they may have different sizes in binary form and they wouldn't have a separator indicating where a frame ends and where the next frame begins. I suggest appending the size information at the beginning of each marshalled frame, that way you will be able to unmarshal all of the frames even if they have different sizes.

As @PiotrK pointed out in his answer, you could use [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers). However, I don't recommend it for your specific use. Personally, I think this is overkill (Too much work for too little results, protobufs can be a PITA some times).

If you are worried about storage size, you could [LZ4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ4_(compression_algorithm)) the whole thing (if you are concatenating the binary information in memory), or LZ4 each frame (if you are processing each frame individually and then appending it to a file). I recommend the latter one because, depending on the amount of frames, you may run out of memory while you marshal your record.

**Ps: Never use XML, it's cancerous!**

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know is to use some kind of format generator (like [Google Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers)). This has several advantage over using default C# serializer:

1. Versioning of format is as easy as possible; You can add new feature to the format and that will not break replays already existing in the field
2. The result is stored as either text or binary, with binary favorable and having very small footprint (for example if some of your data has default values, it won't be present in output at all - loader will handle them gracefully)
3. It's Google technology! :-)